# How do I filter out subsets of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

this is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2014-03-27', '2014-03-28', '2014-03-31', '2014-04-01', '2014-04-02', '2014-04-03', '2014-04-04', '2014-04-07', '2014-04-07', '2014-04-07'],
                   'income': [1849.04, 1857.62, 1872.34, 1885.52, 1890.9, 1888.77, 1865.09, 1845.04, 1235.04, 2323]

})
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
df = df.iloc[::-1]
```

[image]

How do I get the entire dataframe below a specific date.
I.e. if I specify "2014-04-07" then I want row containing "2014-04-07" and below.
[image]

Likewise if I specify  "2014-04-03", I want "2014-04-02" and below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# boolean filter on index, and then loc to filter the rows
df.loc[df.index < '2014-04-07']
```

```
    income
Date    
2014-04-04  1865.09
2014-04-03  1888.77
2014-04-02  1890.90
2014-04-01  1885.52
2014-03-31  1872.34
2014-03-28  1857.62
2014-03-27  1849.04
```

Comment: a lot easier than I thought it would be!